# Delete a file with the name given in the promt also with specific extention

Tags: python, find, subprocess

```
import subprocess

name = raw_input("Enter the name of the file: ")

subprocess.Popen(["find", "-name", "*.spec", "|", "grep", name, "|", "xargs", "rm"], cwd="/opt/blusapphire/app/master/dist", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have written the above code in python file. My aim is to delete a file ie., abc.spec

So when I execute

```
python <filename>.py
```

It will ask for name of the file. When I have give abc it should delete abc.spec file only

But the above code gives the following error

```
find: paths must precede expression: abc
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello", "|", "cat"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt has rather too many false assumptions to be answered comprehensively.

- `subprocess` does not run a shell by default; `|` and `xargs` are being passed as parameters to `find`
- `raw_input()` returns a string with a newline
- `subprocess.Popen()` is really the wrong tool (and arguably Python is the wrong tool underneath)
- Your shell command pipeline is excessively complex; just use the features of `find`

Try this:

```
from subprocess import check_cmd  # or run once you upgrade to Python 3.6+

name = raw_input("Enter the name of the file: ")  # or input() once you upgrade to Python 3
name = name.rstrip('\n')

check_cmd(['find', '-name', '*%s*.spec' % name, '-delete'])
```

Scripts which require interactive input are generally inferior to scripts which accept command-line parameters; with command-line arguments, you can easily get history, tab completion etc because these are (very very probably) already features of your interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import subprocess
  name = raw_input("Enter the name of the file: ") 
  name = name.rstrip('\n') 
  subprocess.Popen(['find', '-name', '*%s*.spec' % name, '-delete'])
```

My problem is solved.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't address the problem in your question. It is another way to solve it. You should have used the piping infrastructure in subprocess to make your original way work (though this is better).